# what do you mean by System.assert(true) in apex testing?

Tags: force.com, unit-test

We have a code like this -->
NotificationsController notificationsController = new NotificationsController();

**System.assert(true);**

```
        notificationsController.ClickBtnBackToDB();
        notificationsController.getNotificationName();
        notificationsController.getNotificationDetailBOList();
        notificationsController.getDisplayCompanyWebsite();
        notificationsController.getDisplayCurrencyName();
        notificationsController.getDisplaySupplierCompany();

        **System.assert(true);**
        notificationsController.getDisplayPurchaserCompany();
        notificationsController.getDisplayAgreementStatus();
        notificationsController.getDisplayTRAId();
        notificationsController.getDisplayBSAId();
        notificationsController.getDisplayETAId();
        notificationsController.getDisplayCompanyId();
        notificationsController.getDisplayUserId();
        notificationsController.getDisplayUserName();
        notificationsController.getDisplayEmail();
        **System.assert(true);**
```

why we have used system.assert(true) for so many times ?

Comment: I think you'll need to ask that to the person who wrote the code. All we can do is guess, as it doesn't have much technical reason, nor contains the optional assert message.

Comment: @Amit Can you provide your class and test class

Comment: or maybe they intended to add something more meaningful there but they forgot...

Answer (score 3):

This looks to me like someone who didn't know how to write unit tests was told to add some asserts to confirm behaviour.  These asserts are adding nothing as the true literal can never be any other value.

There's no requirement from the Salesforce platform for unit tests to have assert statements in order to deploy to production - it does, however, mean that the code is being covered rather than tested as all it proves is that the test scenario doesn't throw an error.

Comment: Checkmarx complains at unit test that have no asserts. Not that I'd call this a "solution".

Comment: @Bob Buzzard what would the final result of using an assert in our code...as on execution, i dont see it to be popping up some message on my screen or in the logs i could see any entry of its....I am unable to understand,where exactly does it get recorded that i can see the entry similar to system.debug.?

Comment: If you have an assert and it succeeds, you won't see anything aside from the unit test passing.  If the assert fails, the unit test will also fail.